# Excel! Handling money symbol and percentage

Tags: microsoft-excel, worksheet-function

So, what I have to do is to copy a list of prices and add a certain percentage to a various lists. What I did is an excel where I paste the list and it adds the percentage automatically, with this:

`=(A2*$H$3)+A2`

being A2 the cell that I want to use, and H3 the percentage I want to add,

My problem is that the lists that I copy are from Word, and prices have its money symbol like: "$ 46,70", and they don´t let me operate! I have to erase them by hand.

Is there any way to ignore them?

Comment: Is your system set to use comma as the decimal separator?

Answer (score 0):

You need to format the source and target cells as *currency*:

- Select the cells you want to format
- On the Home tab, click the Dialog Box Launcher next to Number
  or press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>1</kbd> to open the Format Cells dialog box
- In the Format Cells dialog box, in the Category list, click Currency or Accounting.
- In the Symbol box, click the currency symbol that you want.

For more information see the article
[Format numbers as currency](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/format-numbers-as-currency-0a03bb38-1a07-458d-9e30-2b54366bc7a4).